# 3G Data connection assistant on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 3g, nexus-4

I still couldn't manage to create a woeking 3g data connection with Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview on my Nexus 4 phone :-(

Will there be a setup assistant on the phone once version 1.0 is ou tu help one to get this working?

Thanx in advance!

Cheers
Andi